# What should I do about nails that are protruding through the soffit?

Tags: roof

Had new roof put on, but when I came home the nails had come through the soffit and split the wood and protrude.  Roofer wants to clip off nail, and wood putty the wood.  I don't think this is a good long term solution.  Should I stand my ground and require new soffits?

Comment: Are the nails 2 feet long or something? How do they reach from the roof through the soffit?

Comment: This is a common problem with roofers that do not gauge the length of their nails or staples correctly, and they did not think to look at the soffits to see how they were finished. If they clipped them off, will the roofer repaint? The broken out splinters are the biggest eyesore.

Comment: My guess is that there is no actual soffit, and the home simply has painted undersides to the roof sheathing. @pamhere, please clarify and/or provide photos.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually pretty professional of the Roofer & should work out fine, putty really does do an amazing job. However, see if the Roofer might go for one more step & put up a face or crown-molding that may result in an overall improvement.

Comment: My roofer used the same solution in the dormer walls, which were thinner than he ecpected: clip nails, repair plaster, repaint. However, ih the area is that thin you might want to consider buiding it out and instzlling a layer of insulation.

Answer (score 0):

when I installed the roofing on my house I did the same thing and in hind sight I could have used shorter nails , but the building code in my area wants the roof nails to penetrate at least 3/4 inches into the sheathing. Anyway... my solution was to cover the roof eaves by screwing 3/8" rough sawn siding to the rafters bottom edge enclosing each bay and covering the underside of the sheathing and exposed nail points.